# How can i say this? Is it correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

How can i say that something is left. I mean when there are some items left.
Is it:

> That's what it's left from the party.

Is that correct?

Comment: No, your text would *never* be "correct". Using present tense, you could say *That's **what is** / **what's** left [over] **from** the party* if you were talking about, say, uneaten party food and drink. But if you were talking about things that guests accidentally forgot to take home (coats, mobile phones, etc.) you'd almost certainly use Past Tense (referring back to *when they forgot them*, rather than "current status"): *That's what **was left** [behind] **at** the party.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That's what's left from the party

or

> That's what is left from the party